# Related questions on the audience of 1 John 2:12–14

Tags: discussion

Since neither of these questions have an accepted answer, they are not technically duplicates, but they may be candidates for merging:

1. [1st John 2:12-14: little children, young men and fathers](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/17437/423)
2. [Who are the “children”, “fathers” and “young men” addressed in 1 John 2?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1337/423)

The majority of the answers to these two questions are very poor and I've voted to delete many of the answers to them.

The question for #2 is much clearer and simpler to answer than the wall of text in #1, so my recommendation is to merge #1 into #2 so that question #2 survives.

---

<sub>**Note**</sub>

<sub>I'm also aware of the question entitled, ["What is the proper understanding of παιδία in 1 John?"](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/28107/423) While it partially overlaps in reference to these verses, the question is broader and asks about this specific term throughout the entire book of 1 John.</sub>